# Spring cloud task "Deadlock found when trying to get lock"

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I am facing problems while setting up spring cloud task:

- It is throwing "Deadlock found when trying to get lock" exception. Don't know whats wrong in code?
- Limit number of concurrent task per processor.

Comment: Can you please provide logs/stack traces with your errors?

Comment: Are you trying to insert/update data in the database? Can you provide more details on when/what your code is trying to do before it got the error? Stack trace will also help.

Comment: Yes I am trying to some CRUD operations on DB. Deadlock issue is intermittent. But I want to know how to control number of task launched by Launcher at a time because currently it is starting all task instance in one go.